# Will an app built with MyFaces 2.1.11 run on Tomcat 6.0.24?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, myfaces

I am just starting a new web application (as a learning project). I have some freedom to choose what framework I use, but I must use JavaEE, it must be MVC, and it must run on Tomcat 6.0.24. I've decided to go with JSF 2, using the MyFaces implementation (the choice of MyFaces was arbitrary...I just need to get started with something to learn, but I wanted it to be something used in practice for real-world apps). The latest release is 2.1.11, and I figured I'd go with that. However, will I run into any problems trying to run an app built with MyFaces 2.1.11 on Tomcat 6.0.24? I'm new to Java web development and JSF, so I wasn't sure if there'd be any issues, but I don't want to get down this path (especially starting from scratch with whichever framework I use) and realize that my app won't work with Tomcat 6.0.24. Thanks.

Comment: Just [download](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) Tomcat 6.0.24 and try it? In any way .. the minimum requirements of JSF 2.1 states among others Servlet 2.5.

Comment: So I guess you don't see anything obvious that would prevent it from working. I'll go ahead and get started with it and see what happens. I'm so new to this, and even getting set up to do a test app to see if it works will take me some time/learning, so I just wanted to avoid that work if it were obvious (to someone with more experience) that it wasn't going to work out. I'll check the Tomcat 6 specs to see if it includes Servlet 2.5...if you know off hand, please tell. Thanks.

Comment: I know the answer off hand, but I don't want to encourage zero-effort questions like this being asked when the answer can already be found by just looking at requirements and specs or even just experimenting.

Comment: "Zero-effort" from your perspective, I guess. I've been reading stuff for a couple of days trying to get my mind around all the new terminology, different technology, and frameworks out there, so I guess I wouldn't consider it zero effort. Anyway, thanks for the responses and for pointing me to the specs.

Comment: @neizan *I've been reading stuff for a couple of days trying to get my mind around all the new terminology* you will never learn **just by reading**, try something like setting up the tomcat and write a small JSF2 app using MyFaces (that's what BalusC means with "zero-effort"). Your case is like *I wanna learn to swim without jumping into the pool*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I've done some more reading and practicing over the past week, things have become clearer and the feeling of being overwhelmed by buzzwords has subsided a bit. In retrospect, getting JSF 2 and JSTL in place were pretty easy, and I now have what I think is a fully functional development environment.

Confirming the [supported Servlet/JSF versions in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) was a cinch. Using Eclipse Indigo, JavaEE 6, Apache MyFaces 2.1.11, and JSTL 1.2.1, my (very simple) test apps worked on Tomcat 6.0.24.

This was a very specific question, so I'm not sure whether it will be of use for anyone else, but I figured I'd give an answer just for completeness. Thanks to BalusC for his input on this question and for his many other contributions on SO!